# Sails.js multiple databases in multiple environments

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have been going round in circles trying to get this to work how I *think*  it should in sails v 0.11.0

I have my development.js as follows

```
module.exports = {

connections: {
    conn1: {
        adapter: 'sails-sqlserver',
        user: 'user',
        password: 'pass',
        server: 'server1',
        database: 'db1',

        options: {
            encrypt: true
        }
    },


    conn2: {
        adapter: 'sails-sqlserver',
        user: 'user',
        password: 'pass',
        server: 'server1',
        database: 'db2',

        options: {
            encrypt: true
        }
    }
},

    models:
    {
        firstconn: 'conn1',
        secondconn: 'conn2'
    }

};
```

My connection.js is empty

In my controller I am trying to echo the connection and user it to get a list of users:

UsersController:

```
var sql = require('mssql');

    module.exports = {
        hi: function (req, res) {

            console.log(sails.config.firstconn);

            var connection = new sql.Connection(sails.config.firstconn, function (err) {
                var request = new sql.Request(connection);
                request.query('SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Perms_Users]', function (err, recordsets) {
                    res.send(recordsets)
                });
            });
        }
    };
```

However my connection is always null?

I am running in development, can someone point out what I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was very easy!

sails.config.connections.conn1 gives access to the modal

Comment: You should validate your answer then.

Comment: I have another 20 hours before I can :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add `connection: 'dbname'` to your model to access the database. The models block in development should be the default db connection and and configuration to use.

For model settings
http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html

In depth models:
http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Models.html